# sudo freshclam failed -- permission issue?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, clamav

I am getting the following error while trying to manually run `freshclam` on Ubuntu 18.04, as super user (**I already stopped the daemon as described in other questions**).

```
# sudo freshclam 
Wed May 22 07:33:08 2019 -> ClamAV update process started at Wed May 22 07:33:08 2019
Wed May 22 07:33:08 2019 -> ^Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
Wed May 22 07:33:08 2019 -> ^Local version: 0.100.3 Recommended version: 0.101.2
Wed May 22 07:33:08 2019 -> DON'T PANIC! Read https://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading-clamav
Wed May 22 07:33:32 2019 -> getfile: Can't write 8192 bytes to /var/lib/clamav/clamav-61ad7aac1e8b42b507986f04c334427d.tmp/clamav-cba52511a773dacb076f4e204c4b1a77.tmp
Wed May 22 07:33:32 2019 -> ^Can't download main.cvd from db.local.clamav.net
Wed May 22 07:33:33 2019 -> *Can't query main.0.93.0.0.6810DA54.ping.clamav.net
```

Manually creating the file works though, so I'm not sure this is a permission issue.

```
# mkdir /var/lib/clamav/clamav-63297260eb8cf259cb59552e4bddc3b3.tmp/
# dd if=/dev/urandom of=/var/lib/clamav/clamav-63297260eb8cf259cb59552e4bddc3b3.tmp/clamav-7802c73731c6f7f34959ac4d37b24f6e.tmp count=5840
5840+0 records in
5840+0 records out
2990080 bytes (3.0 MB, 2.9 MiB) copied, 0.0424701 s, 70.4 MB/s
```

I found the two sources below:

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/getfile-cant-write-1448-bytes-to-usr-share-clamav-clamav-917a563483a6171fe02eac005.125857/

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/warning-can%27t-download-main-cvd-from-db-local-clamav-net-786955/

But what they were suggesting did not help either (I don't have quotas, and I tried stopping AppArmor, but still the same issue.)

Any other ideas, what I should check?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the cause: **the disk was full**.

To make the answer complete, I'm leaving here my solution, how to expand the disk size using volumes:

```
# df -h /
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.7G     0 100% /
```

We need `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

```
# lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 4.00 GiB (1024 extents) to <14.00 GiB (3583 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.


# resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 2
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is now 3668992 (4k) blocks long.


# df -h /
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   14G  3.7G  9.5G  28% /


# freshclam 
Wed May 22 08:06:49 2019 -> ClamAV update process started at Wed May 22 08:06:49 2019
Wed May 22 08:06:49 2019 -> ^Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
Wed May 22 08:06:49 2019 -> ^Local version: 0.100.3 Recommended version: 0.101.2
Wed May 22 08:06:49 2019 -> DON'T PANIC! Read https://www.clamav.net/documents/upgrading-clamav
Wed May 22 08:07:15 2019 -> Downloading main.cvd [100%]
Wed May 22 08:07:23 2019 -> main.cvd updated (version: 58, sigs: 4566249, f-level: 60, builder: sigmgr)
Wed May 22 08:07:24 2019 -> *Can't query main.58.93.1.0.6810DB54.ping.clamav.net
Wed May 22 08:07:32 2019 -> Downloading daily.cvd [100%]
Wed May 22 08:07:49 2019 -> daily.cvd updated (version: 25456, sigs: 1576656, f-level: 63, builder: raynman)
Wed May 22 08:07:49 2019 -> *Can't query daily.25456.93.1.0.6810DB54.ping.clamav.net
Wed May 22 08:07:49 2019 -> Downloading bytecode.cvd [100%]
Wed May 22 08:07:50 2019 -> bytecode.cvd updated (version: 328, sigs: 94, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
Wed May 22 08:07:50 2019 -> *Can't query bytecode.328.93.1.0.6810DB54.ping.clamav.net
Wed May 22 08:07:54 2019 -> Database updated (6142999 signatures) from db.local.clamav.net (IP: 104.16.219.84)
Wed May 22 08:07:54 2019 -> !NotifyClamd: Can't find or parse configuration file /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
```